# my server cannot open cakephp3 projects

Tags: cakephp, wamp

I am suddenly getting this error below every time I open cakephp3 project. Previously I had been opening many such projects many times a day on the same pc.
I am using win7, wamp64 with cakephp3. In the php.ini file the extension existsextension=php_intl.dll  exists so what is the problem? I can run phpinfo

Fatal error: You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check

1. Open /wamp64/bin/php/php.ini
2. Change **;extension=php_intl.dll** to **extension=php_intl.dll** (remove the semicolon)
3. Copy all the /wamp64/bin/php/ic*.dll files to /wamp64/bin/apache/bin then click **Restart All Services** in the Wamp try icon from your task bar.

**N.B:** Also you have to check **php_intl.dll** exist in  /wamp64/bin/php/ext/

Update:

try to reinstall the Apache **`trayicon>>Apache>>Service Administration>>Install Service`** then click **Restart All Services** in the Wamp tray

Comment: there is no semicolon to remove extension=php_intl.dll as thiswas working fine yesterday. Restarting the services doesnt fix anything and php.ini cant be found from the tray but the file exists in the wamp64 menu. Has wamp64 crashed?

Comment: Please check **\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.18\bin\php.ini** there also exist the **php.ini** or **php.ini shortcut** file

Comment: This file php.ini is now empty which is why it isnt working. I think wamp64 crashed and wiped the file . how can i get this back? \wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.18\bin\php.ini

Comment: try to reinstall the Apache  **trayicon>>Apache>>Service Administration>>Install Service** then  click **Restart All Services** in the Wamp tray

Comment: SOLUTION:
Using wampmanager icon menus do -

wampmanager -> Apache -> Version -> 2.4.9 ( click on the version number ) this will rebuild the SYMLINKS for this and other files in \wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin